# PUT Request calls to API from SPA Frontend throws 403 Forbidden Status Code

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, frontend, asp.net-core-webapi, ubuntu-18.04

I have a web API hosted in an Ubuntu server (18.04 LTS) with all PUT endpoints responding appropriately when call with Postman or swagger. But same PUT endpoints called by a React Frontend app throws 403 Forbidden status code. The React app is also hosted on the same server. These endpoints are not secured so I'm confused with the status despite the fact that it works without the React app.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: it would be easier to help if you can share some code

Comment: @fizmhd The code works very fine. In fact it runs perfectly on my staging server. But on my production server, this happens. And the build that works in staging is the same as that in production. I really think it's a server problem but don't know how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the issue had nothing to do with the code. The Application Firewall had PUT requests disabled. Enabling it solved the problem.